# Sorting and Comparing Arraylist of Integer Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist of integer arrays and I want to go through each array from the 1st one and compare it to all the previous arrays in the arraylist. If the array is equal to any of the previous arrays then the program should output "repeat" and stop the program. Also, is there any way to sort the arrays so that the program runs faster and more efficient? Thanks in advance.

Example

```
Arraylist<int[]> numbers = new Arraylist<int[]>();

   int[] num1 = new int[]{1,2,3};
   int[] num2 = new int[]{2,3,5};
   int[] num3 = new int[]{1,2,3};
   int[] num4 = new int[]{3,2,6};

numbers.add(num1);
numbers.add(num2);
numbers.add(num3);
numbers.add(num4);

(Sorting to make more efficient and faster)

(Comparing)
```

The program should print out "repeat" and stop after it compares num3 to num1 because they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Put your arrays in a small wrapper that implements `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Then put them in a `HashSet` using the `add()` method. If the `add` method returns `false`, you've got a duplicate.

You can use `Arrays.hashCode` for the return value of `hashCode()` and `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` to implement `equals()`.

The only thing is that to create a list afterwards you will need to retrieve the objects out of the `Set`, get the byte array and put it in a list. You can use `List.addAll()` to put the wrapper objects in a list though. But maybe you want to keep with a `Set`, depends on the further use.

---

OK, so maybe that's a bit advanced, I've made an implementation for you:

```
public class Dupes {

    public static class WrappedArray {
        public WrappedArray(int[] wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        public int[] getWrapped() {
            return this.wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof WrappedArray)) {
                return false;
            }
            WrappedArray that = (WrappedArray) obj;
            return Arrays.equals(this.wrapped, that.wrapped);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(wrapped);
        }

        private final int[] wrapped;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> numbers = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        int[] num1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] num2 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5 };
        int[] num3 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] num4 = new int[] { 3, 2, 6 };

        numbers.add(num1);
        numbers.add(num2);
        numbers.add(num3);
        numbers.add(num4);

        Set<WrappedArray> wrappedNumberSet = new HashSet<>();

        int index = 1;
        for (int[] number : numbers) {
            if (!wrappedNumberSet.add(new WrappedArray(number))) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate num" + index);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Java, what is hashCode()? and how do you use it?

Comment: Hashcode returns a value that is *usually* different for any data object. `HashSet` uses this to find the values, then performs an `equals` to see if they are identical.

Comment: OK, so a `Set` is a set of objects without duplicates. It's a `Collection` just like `List`. `HashSet` is an implementation that uses the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method of objects to implement a set. There is also `SortedSet` which orders elements using the `compareTo()` method or a special `Comparator`. `TreeSet` is the default implementation. This is all easy to find using a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the inner array with a sort such as a quicksort.

You can compare the arrays by doing Arrays.equals(num1,num3); ,which only works if the arrays are sorted.

From Java doc

"Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order"

Comment: Are you sure? I think you need `Arrays.equals()` for that, the Java `[I.equals()` inherits directly from Object, in other words, it compares the reference.

Comment: You were correct. Edited solution.